# Linq query inside controller is returning an array with a lot of undesired duplicated data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have an unsual problem with how a controller is returning results.

I am using .Net Core Entity Framework and SQL Server for my project.

The data that is being returned is one Author row from the AuthorList table, and 3 Book rows from the AuthorBooks table.

The books have an authorId that links them to the AuthorList table.

In SQL I just do a `SELECT * FROM AuthorBooks WHERE authorId = 'author_33'`

And that returns the 3 rows of books from AuthorBooks.

But the JSON returned is not how I need it to be.

It is listing an array , with each book, with an author array inside of it. So it is duplicating a lot of data, like this:

```
[
    {
        "bookId": "1a",
        "authorId": "author_33",
        "bookText": "English_Variant1",
        "author": {
            "authorId": "author_33",
            "authorText": "Bio Book 102",
            "authorBooks": [
                {
                    "bookId": "4a",
                    "authorId": "author_33",
                    "bookText": "English",
                },
                {
                    "bookId": "9a",
                    "authorId": "author_33",
                    "bookText": "Spanish",
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "bookId": "4a",
        "authorId": "author_33",
        "bookText": "English",
        "author": {
            "authorId": "author_33",
            "authorText": "Bio Book 102",
            "authorBooks": [
                {
                    "bookId": "1a",
                    "authorId": "author_33",
                    "bookText": "English_Variant1",
                },
                {
                    "bookId": "9a",
                    "authorId": "author_33",
                    "bookText": "Spanish",
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "bookId": "9a",
        "authorId": "author_33",
        "bookText": "Spanish",
        "author": {
            "authorId": "author_33",
            "authorText": "Bio Book 102",
            "authorBooks": [
                {
                    "bookId": "1a",
                    "authorId": "author_33",
                    "bookText": "English_Variant1",
                },
                {
                    "bookId": "4a",
                    "authorId": "author_33",
                    "bookText": "English",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

But I need it to look like this (notice how much nicer this looks):

```
"author": {
"authorId": "author_33",
"authorText": "Bio Book 102",
"authorBooks": 
            [
                {
                "bookId": "1a",
                "authorId": "author_33",
                "bookText": "English_Variant1",
                },
                {
                    "bookId": "4a",
                    "authorId": "author_33",
                    "bookText": "English",
                },
                {
                    "bookId": "9a",
                    "authorId": "author_33",
                    "bookText": "Spanish",
                }
            ]
}
```

The controller that is returning the JSON data is fairly straight forward:

```
[HttpGet("GetBooksByAuthorId/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AuthorBooks>>> GetBooksByAuthorId(Guid id)
{
   var booksByAuthor = await _context.AuthorBooks.Where(q => q.AuthorId == id).ToListAsync();
   return booksByAuthor;
}
```

Here is my model for AuthorBooks:

```
public partial class AuthorBooks
{
    public Guid BookId { get; set; }
    public Guid? AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string BookText { get; set; }

    public virtual AuthorList Author { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my model for AuthorList:

```
public partial class AuthorList
{
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorText { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorBooks> AuthorBooks { get; set; }
}
```

Inside my database context, they look like this:

AuthorBooks:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorBooks>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.BookId);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Author)
        .WithMany(p => p.AuthorBooks)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.AuthorId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)

    entity.ToTable("AuthorBooks");

    entity.Property(e => e.BookId)
        .HasColumnName("BookId");

    entity.Property(e => e.AuthorId)
        .HasColumnName("AuthorId");

    entity.Property(e => e.BookText)
        .HasColumnName("BookText");

});
```

AuthorList:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AuthorList>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.AuthorId);
    entity.ToTable("AuthorList");

    entity.Property(e => e.AuthorId)
        .HasColumnName("AuthorId");

    entity.Property(e => e.AuthorText)
        .HasColumnName("AuthorText");
});
```

I think it may have to do with the ICollections that I am using in the models.

But when I remove those, I get errors in my database context class.

So I am kind of stuck as to what to do.

Is there a way to format this so that it doesn't duplicate a lot of the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you can query for the author including the related books, and change the return type of your action method accordingly to reflect the type of the query result -

```
[HttpGet("GetBooksByAuthorId/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<AuthorList>> GetBooksByAuthorId(Guid id)
{
    var authorWithBooks = await _context.AuthorLists
                            .Include(p=> p.AuthorBooks)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p=> p.AuthorId == id);
    return authorWithBooks;
}
```

This will match your expected JSON result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to return the root object "AuthorList", not "AuthorBooks." Find the correct Author on your context and return it instead.

Comment: thanks, but I do want to return the `AuthorBooks` by `Author`.

Comment: I understand that, but look at your payloads. You're directly serializing your entities resulting in the collection of "AuthorBooks" on "AuthorList" being serialized (hence the duplication). If you returned "AuthorList" you'd still get your "AuthorBooks" but they would instead be the way you want them. Give it a try and see.

Comment: thanks so you mean do this? `var booksByAuthor = await _context.AuthorList.Where(q => q.AuthorId == id).ToListAsync();`